# Creating templates using functions to reduce redundancy in PHP

Tags: php, html, function, templates

I am writing a website from scratch for fun (as a beginner web developer who comes from C++) and I noticed a lot of my pages have the same code; 95% actually. So I wanted to create a function in PHP to minimize redundant code inside of my website project. Similar to how we make a function in any other language, c++ , java ; etc, I want to make a function that passes parameters into a called php file to write the specific web page.

This is the code I want to make individual pages look like. Instead of having 100+ lines of the same code in multiple files, I wanted to just do something like this and pass it into the template.php file to make it more efficient and or smaller in size (less redundant code).

```
$title = "Example_Title";
$author = "Example_Author";
$date = "January 1, 1999";
$article = "Example_Body";
include('template.php');
setDependencies($title, $author, $date, $article);
```

And this is the template I wanted to use, where I pass the values in, set them, then use it in the html code under the declared PHP.

```
<?php 
$this_title = "";
$this_author = "";
$this_date = "";
$this_article = "";

function setDependencies($title, $author, $date, $article){
    $this_title = $title;
    $this_author = $author;
    $this_date = $date;
    $this_article = $article;
}
?>

<body>
<p>Written by <?php $this_author ?> on <?php $this_date ?></p>
</body>
```

The code, "written by ..." inside the body tag is just a line of code I used to see if this would display after being called (included) but it just ended up writing "Written by  on".

I realized the main issue with this was the include('template.php') function included everything of the template.php and then executed the setDependencies() after, so the function call did nothing.

I tried including template.php twice, first one to get setDependencies() included, the second to execute the html, but that yielded in error as it declared setDependencies twice and the website did not like that. I also tried making three files instead of two, where I declared the values of title, author, date and article and pushed it to the second file where the third file calls it for the values needed in the html portion, where I then called it inside of the first file but that yielded the same result of the calling-the-same-function-miltiple-times error.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: to avoid the error that "function already declared", you can use "function_exists" to check if yourFunction not exist and then declare yourFunction..  if(!function_exists('myfunction')){ function myfunction(){ ..mycode.. } }

Comment: I would just modify the code that sets variables in`template.php` to something like `if (!isset($this_title)) $this_title = "";`